# XNA issue with 3d model textures path

Tags: c#, xna, blender

I am a newbie in `XNA`.
i have a problem in loading free *3d models* as it has a absolute path for the textures in the artist's machine which i don't have in mine.
It always come up with error of *missing texture* because the *wrong path*.
I want to know how to edit this path to be relative, and it would be great if it automated as most of the models have more than three textures.

Comment: Generally, when you export from 3d editor, you may set to use relative path for textures, so the answer depends on your 3d editing software and 3d model format.

Comment: What file format are these models in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of alternatives:

1. Open the model in a 3D-editing software and change the path.
2. Open the model with notepad (or any other text-editor) and find and replace all paths.
3. Write a program that takes a folder or file-set as argument and let it do the work for you. (This is good if you run in to the same problem with another project)
4. Find a program someone else has already made for this.